# Python Sockets, requesting file from server then waiting to receive it

Tags: python, file, sockets, send, recv

I am attempting to send a string to my server from my client with a specific filename and then send that file to the client. For some reason it hangs even after it's received all of the file. It hangs on the:

```
m = s.recv(1024)
```

**client.py**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.168.1.2", 54321))
s.send(b"File:test.txt")
f = open("newfile.txt", "wb")
data = None
while True:
    m = s.recv(1024)
    data = m
    if m:
        while m:
            m = s.recv(1024)
            data += m
        else:
            break
f.write(data)
f.close()
print("Done receiving")
```

**server.py**

```
import socket
import os

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("", 54321))

while True:
    client_input = c.recv(1024)
    command = client_input.split(":")[0]
    if command == "File":
        command_parameter = client_input.split(":")[1]
        f = open(command_parameter, "rb")
        l = os.path.getsize(command_parameter)
        m = f.read(l)
        c.sendall(m)
        f.close()
```

Comment: Note: your server sample code doesn't show how `c` is accepted from the listen socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**

The reason `recv` blocks is because the socket connection is not shutdown after the file data was sent. The implementation currently has no way to know when the communication is over, which results in a deadlock between the two, remote processes. To avoid this, close the socket connection in the server, which will generate an end-of-file event in the client (i.e. `recv` returns a zero-length string).

**More insight**

Whenever you design any software where two processes communicate with each other, you have to define a *protocol* that disambiguates the communication such that both peers know exactly which state they are in at all times. Typically this involves using the syntax of the communication to help guide the interpretation of the data.

Currently, there are some problems with your implementation: it doesn't define an adequate protocol to resolve potential ambiguity. This becomes apparent when you consider the fact that each call to `send` in one peer doesn't necessarily correspond to exactly one call to `recv` in the other. That is, the calls to `send` and `recv` are not necessarily one-to-one. Consider sending the file name to the server on a heavily congested network: perhaps only half of the file name makes it to the server when the first call to `recv` returns. The server has no way (currently) to know if it has finished receiving the file name. The same is true in the client: how does the client know when the file has finished?

To work around this, we can introduce some syntax into the protocol and some logic into the server to ensure we get the complete file name before continuing. A simple solution would be to use an EOL character, i.e. `\n` to denote the end of the client's message. Now, 99.99% of the time in your testing this will take a single call to `recv` to read in. However you have to anticipate the cases in which it might take more than one call to `recv`. This can be implemented using a loop, obviously.

The client end is simpler for this demo. If the communication is over after the sending of the file, then that event can be used to denote the end of the data stream. This happens when the server closes the connection on its end.

If we were to expand the implementation to, say, allow for requests for multiple, back-to-back files, then we'd have to introduce some mechanism in the protocol for distinguishing the end of one file and the beginning of the next. Note that this also means the server would need to potentially buffer extra bytes that it reads in on previous iterations in case there is overlap. A stream implementation is generally useful for these sorts of things.